# Praw & Discord.py: The bot keep sending the same meme. I want the bot to send different meme whenever it is asked

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, praw, asyncpraw

I am trying to create a `listener` for meme. The bot will respond to the message when it has `"meme"` in it. It has to send a meme. I am using Praw for that purpose.

This is the code I have written:

```
@nd.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == nd.user:
        return
    
    def findCoindences(w):
        return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w)).search
    content = message.content
    reaction = ""
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
    for submission in subreddit.random():
        submission_link = submission.url
    
    if findCoindences('meme')(content.lower()):
        await message.reply(submission_link)
        await message.add_reaction(f"<{reaction}>")
```

*Note: I have defined `reddit` already above some lines. That is not the cause I guess.*

---

#### The problem:

Whenever I send `meme` in the chat it sends the same meme every time. I want it to be different but don't know where I am having this issue.

This is what it looks like:
[image: Ufff]

Comment: `random_submission = reddit.subreddit('memes').random()`. I am not sure what iterating over `subreddit.random()` is even doing.

Comment: @Goion It throws an error. I had tried it before. `Submission is not iterable`.

Comment: Dude, you have the submission. Just post the link. Why do you want to iterate so badly?

Comment: Umm! I don't know how to work with Praw friend. I never used it. You might need to tell me.

Comment: I have answered your question. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for you to iterate over anything. Praw provides a method which allows you to grab a random submission from a subreddit.

**Documentation:**
[random()](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.random)

**Code:**

```
@nd.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == nd.user:
        return
    
    def findCoindences(w):
        return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w)).search
    content = message.content
    reaction = ""
    
    if findCoindences('meme')(content.lower()):
        random_submission = reddit.subreddit('memes').random()
        await message.reply(random_submission.url)
        await message.add_reaction(f"<{reaction}>")
```

> Note: I have move the random_submission inside the `If-statement` because there is no need for you to look up a submission if the message doesn't say "meme". It would just waste rate limit.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav Np. I am pretty sure you would have been able to figure it out as well if you took a minute to think.

Comment: Yep! Maybe! But I know now anyways.